# How can I add System.Data.SqlClient references for my custom code in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

```
public string getLabel(int ReportID, int labelID)
{
    string s;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection myConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=*****;Persist Security Info=True;Password=****;User ID=*********;Initial Catalog=iLoyaltyDW");
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
    myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    myCommand.CommandText = "select ....";
    myConnection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        s = reader.GetString(0);
    }

    return s;         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to add a reference to the assembly from the report properties U/I

Take a look here for steps and caveats:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155974.aspx